# Why isn't webpack using my .map files?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

When I inspect my application in Chrome debugger, I see only webpack's raw output source js bundled file. I'd like to see my typescript files as they appear in my IDE, or even a prettier javascript file, but none of that is working. Here's what I have:

Running in Visual Studio 2017.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
/// <binding BeforeBuild='Run - Development' />
"use strict";

var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    context: __dirname + "/Scripts/App",
    entry: './index.ts',
    output: {
        filename: "index.js",
        path: __dirname + '/Build/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                enforce: "pre",
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "source-map-loader",
            },
            {
                enforce: "pre",
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                use: "source-map-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "ts-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"]
    }
};
```

App directory structure:

```
Root
  /Build
  /Scripts
    /App
      /Models
        Gender.ts
        Person.ts
      index.ts <-- entry point
tsconfig.json
webpack.config.json
```

When I build, typescript compilation is putting *.js and *.js.map files in the ~/Scripts/App/ directory.

Then webpack doing its thing and putting index.js in the ~/Build/ directory.

When I debug and run in Chrome, I see:

[image]

Note how there's no typescript files, and the contents of the js file are the raw output of webpack. No map file seems to be working.

In the output from webpack I see:

`sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,eyJ2ZX.........`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your typescript files are stored inside `webpack://` folder, just look inside it. Or to quickly search for a file in Chrome Dev Tool, press `ctrl + p` then just type the name of the file you are looking for. Note that, you can only see the files **that were downloaded** inside the folder path specified in the html file, any other files won't show up there, for example, in your case, because you tell the browser to load `index.js` located inside the `Build` folder, it appears under `localhost:56085/Build` like in the screenshot, of course your typescript files are not listed there because you do not include them in your html file, even if you did, the browser would not understand them anyways. Once you located the typescript file, you can add breakpoints and the browser will map back to it correctly because you have the option `devtool: 'source-map'` in your webpack config file

Comment: so I'm confused about the .js and .map files that tsc create from the tsconfig. Those sit next to my .ts files, and seem pointless. Isn't webpack's output what the browser gets anyway? Why even use tsconfig? Also breakpoints in my ts files in the webpack directory in chrome that you mentioned aren't being hit. If I place a breakpoint in the webpack output js file and step through, then the ts file gets hit. But it won't get hit if I only have a breakpoint on the ts file.

Comment: First of all. Your `.map` files should be located where their corresponding javascript files are for the debugging to work. Webpack is a module bundler/loader, it converts your `import` statements to function calls to load the requested modules, whatever webpack produces is what you feed to the browser, not the typescript files, the `tsconfig.json` is a configuration file to the typescript transpiler to let it know how to transpile your typescript files, for example, what your target javascript version is, es5 or es6, etc, it decides what output from tsc server you will see inside output file

Comment: So it's ok that my build directory has only the bundled .js file and nothing else in it? And then my raw .ts files have their transpiled .js files and .js.map files that tsc output sitting alongside them?

Comment: To be honest, you shoulsdn't worry about where your output lies, **as long as the .js and .map files are in the same directory** when you include the .js files in your html file, the debugging should work, in fact, your typescript  files can locate anywhere, the browser doesn't care, all it cares about is your .js file and the sourcemap

Comment: So that's the problem. Take a look at the directory structure of my app above. The webpack output file of `~/Build/index.js` has no map files along with it. Those are created by tsc, and are sitting next to the .ts files in their source directory at `~/Scripts/App/...`

Comment: I don't know why you still run tsc server to transpile your ts files while you are specifying to use `ts-loader` for all files with extension `.tsx?`, I don't use `ts-loader` so I am not sure what it produces, I use `awesome-typescript-loader` and when I run webpack, it produces the transpiled javascript files along with their sourcemap files inside the `output.path` that I specify, no need to manually run the tsc server when using one of the typescript loaders

Comment: So what's the point of having a tsconfig.json if webpack and a loader can do that stuff?

Comment: webpack's typescript loaders read the `tsconfig.json` file behind the scene

Comment: Try removing the `context: '...'` field and see if the map files get sent to the `output.path`

Comment: ok so I decided to run `webpack` on the command line and it correctly generated the map file alongside the bundled js file in the output path. I was using a Microsoft Visual Studio extension before to integrate webpack into the VS Task Runner service. What a frustrating ordeal... Apparently it's [bugged here](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebPackTaskRunner/issues/38). Well, thanks for helping me get to the bottom of it!

Comment: I find it useful to add an entry to `package.json`'s `script` block to execute your webpack command

Comment: So how is it that some codebases have the .ts files seemingly situated in the same folder as the transpiled .js files, like in [this video (cued to example)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASFF-DA-HGU&t=2m36s)? Have they simply not been minified and webpacked?

Comment: @ruffin If you transpile TypeScript code using TypeScript compiler `tsc` (and you don't use Webpack) without specifying a build directory, then TypeScript outputs the resulting JavaScript files in the same locations as the original TypeScript source files, in the video you linked, that seemed to be the case because the resulting JavaScript files didn't have Webpack "directives"